# SQL query hangs or crashes

Tags: sqlite, go

Following code on Go 1.16.6 hangs on last Exec call (or crashes if same functions are called from different goroutines)

Both libraries "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3" and "modernc.org/sqlite" give same results

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "testing"

    "database/sql"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
    //  _ "modernc.org/sqlite"
)

func Test_Bug3(t *testing.T) {
    DBPath := "test.db"
    os.Remove(DBPath)
    DB, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", DBPath)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s: %v", DBPath, err)
    }
    if _, err := DB.Exec(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS verdictcache (sha1 text);`); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s: %v", DBPath, err)
    }
    _, err = DB.Exec("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO verdictcache (sha1) VALUES ($1)", "a")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s: %v", DBPath, err)
    }
    _, err = DB.Query("SELECT * FROM verdictcache WHERE sha1=$1", "a")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s: %v", DBPath, err)
    }
    _, err = DB.Exec("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO verdictcache (sha1) VALUES ($1)", "b")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s: %v", DBPath, err)
    }
}
```

Comment: My platform is macOS El Capitan on M1 chip

Comment: You are using a very old and unsupported version of go (1.6) and possibly very old versions of SQLite and the go bindings. Also, how do you know that it hangs on the last Exec?

Comment: 1.6.6 is the lates stable Go version (https://golang.org/dl/), so sql package should be also the lates. Bug appears with both SQLite libraries. I have added test prints after each Exec, bug removed them when positing this question. This is the minimal code that shows this problem

Comment: Ah you mean 1.16.6 not 1.6.6. Maybe good idea to update your question.

Comment: There is no such thing as Go 1.6.6.  1.6.4 was the last of the 1.6 series.

Comment: 1.16.6 is the lates version of Go. Check https://golang.org/dl/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is almost certainly that you did not call `Close()` (or otherwise consumed the rows) on the result returned by `DB.Query(...)`.

Try:

```
func Test_Bug3(t *testing.T) {
    DBPath := "test.db"
    os.Remove(DBPath)
    DB, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", DBPath)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s: %v", DBPath, err)
    }
    if _, err := DB.Exec(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS verdictcache (sha1 text);`); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s: %v", DBPath, err)
    }
    _, err = DB.Exec("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO verdictcache (sha1) VALUES ($1)", "a")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s: %v", DBPath, err)
    }
    res, err := DB.Query("SELECT * FROM verdictcache WHERE sha1=$1", "a")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s: %v", DBPath, err)
    }
    res.Close()
    _, err = DB.Exec("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO verdictcache (sha1) VALUES ($1)", "b")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("%s: %v", DBPath, err)
    }
}
```